2D Zoom to mouse point
So I'm trying to create a zoom function for my 2D camera.
The best result I've got so far is:

But something still feels off, and I just can't seem to pinpoint it.
My code currently, which simply takes the substraction between before and after zoom:
void Zoom(float value, float mx, float my, float w, float h) {
    float bmwx = (w - (w - mx)) * this->zoom, bmwy = (h - (h - my)) * this->zoom; // before
    if (value < 0.0f) this->zoom *= 0.9f;
    if (value > 0.0f) this->zoom *= 1.1f;
    float amwx = (w - (w - mx)) * this->zoom, amwy = (h - (h - my)) * this->zoom; // after
    
    this->center.x += amwx - bmwx;
    this->center.y += amwy - bmwy;
}

My other function, for matrix construction:
void Update(float mx, float my, float w, float h) {
    float hw = w * 0.5f, hh = h * 0.5f;
    float left = -hw + this->center.x;
    float right = hw + this->center.x;
    float top = -hh + this->center.y;
    float bottom = hh + this->center.y;

    this->ortho.InitOrthographic(drx::gfx::ogl::n, drx::gfx::ogl::f, left, right, top, bottom);
    this->mZoom.LoadIdentity();
    this->mZoom.Scale(this->zoom, this->zoom, this->zoom);
    this->matrix = this->ortho * this->mZoom;
}

Update, to current code (Update: which also fails if I move the central point):
void Zoom(float value, float mx, float my, float w, float h) {
    this->os.x += mx * this->zoom;
    this->os.y += my * this->zoom;
    if (value < 0.0f) this->zoom *= 0.75f;
    if (value > 0.0f) this->zoom *= 1.25f;
    this->os.x -= mx * this->zoom;
    this->os.y -= my * this->zoom;

}

void Update(float mx, float my, float w, float h) {
    float hw = w * 0.5f, hh = h * 0.5f;
    float left = -hw + this->center.x;
    float right = hw + this->center.x;
    float top = -hh + this->center.y;
    float bottom = hh + this->center.y;

    this->ortho.InitOrthographic(drx::gfx::ogl::n, drx::gfx::ogl::f, left, right, top, bottom);
    this->mZoom.LoadIdentity();
    this->mZoom.Scale(this->zoom, this->zoom, this->zoom);
    this->mZoom.Translate(this->os.x, this->os.y, 0.0f);
    this->matrix = this->ortho * this->mZoom;
}



A lot of this calculation cancels out for example in (w - (w - mx)), w is subtracted from itself so this could be replaced with just mx the same thing happens four times in your calculation.

@DavidT Yeah, I came to the same conclusion, updated the post with current code. Which still calculates the before and after, but instead of making changes to the  center, I added a translation to the matrix calculation for offset.

Does the zoom update a single canvas, or every object's position and scaling?

@liggiorgio It provides a matrix, which with objects will position and scale.

Answering my own question.
As it turns out, all I was missing, was a screen to world space conversion.
void Zoom(float value, float mx, float my, float w, float h) {
    float x = (2.0f * mx) / w - 1.0f;
    float y = 1.0f - (2.0f * my) / h;
    drx::util::V4F mndc = { x, y, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    drx::util::V4F mouse = this->matrix.Inve() * mndc; 
    this->os.x += mouse.x * this->zoom;
    this->os.y += mouse.y * this->zoom;
    this->zoom *= 1.0f + value;
    this->os.x -= mouse.x * this->zoom;
    this->os.y -= mouse.y * this->zoom;
}

And the result is quite exact:


Sorry I am not directly answering your question but I implemented this in one of my app. It is not in c++ but in lua.
Some code:
-- current zoom
local currzoom = 0.5
local zoomstart = currzoom
canvaslayer:setScale(currzoom)

-- thank you very much hgy29 & keszegh :-)
local pointerstartx, pointerstarty = 0, 0
local canvasposx, canvasposy = 0, 0
local offsetx, offsety = 0, 0

stage:addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_DOWN, function(e)
    pointerstartx, pointerstarty = stage:globalToLocal(e.rx, e.ry)
    e:stopPropagation()
end)
stage:addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_MOVE, function(e)
    canvasposx, canvasposy = canvaslayer:getPosition()
    offsetx = e.rx - pointerstartx
    offsety = e.ry - pointerstarty
    canvasposx += offsetx
    canvasposy += offsety
    canvaslayer:setPosition(canvasposx, canvasposy)
    pointerstartx, pointerstarty = stage:globalToLocal(e.rx, e.ry)
    e:stopPropagation()
end)
stage:addEventListener(Event.MOUSE_WHEEL, function(e) -- e.wheel = +- 120
    zoomstart = currzoom
    pointerstartx, pointerstarty = stage:globalToLocal(e.rx, e.ry)
    canvasposx, canvasposy = canvaslayer:getPosition()
    -- local viewportZoom=math.clamp(self.zoomStart*2^((self.panStart.ry-newY)/100),_MIN_ZOOM,_MAX_ZOOM)
    currzoom = zoomstart + e.wheel/120/4
    if currzoom <= 0.2 then currzoom = 0.2 end
    if currzoom >= 2 then currzoom = 2 end
    canvaslayer:setScale(currzoom)
    local viewportx = canvasposx + (pointerstartx - canvasposx) * (1 - currzoom/zoomstart)
    local viewporty = canvasposy + (pointerstarty - canvasposy) * (1 - currzoom/zoomstart)
    canvaslayer:setPosition(viewportx, viewporty)
    e:stopPropagation()
end)

And the link to the example https://wiki.gideros.rocks/index.php/Ftf_snippets#ZOOM_SPRITE_TO_MOUSE_POSITION_.40hgy29.2C_.40keszegh
Hope this could somehow help you!

I tried scissoring your code for the zooming part, but couldn't get the desired result.

Can you describe how the result differed from what you desired? The more specific you can be, the better it guides answers in useful directions.

@DMGregory For me it zoomed towards 0, 0, but that could be that I couldn't understand the variables correctly.
